# How to adjust context menu to always keep it within the table frame

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I am struggleing in issue. The issue that i am trying to popup context menu but when i click at the edges of the container div. the context menu getting flow out from this container div.

Example :
This is the menu when i click somewhere away from the edges.

[image]

This what happen if i click near to the edges.

[image]

HTML:-

```
<div id="rows-menu-wrapper-container" class="rows-menu-wrapper-container" style="/*display: none;*/" onclick="$(this).remove()">
    <div id="rows-menu-wrapper" class="rows-menu-wrapper">
        <div id="rows-menu-wrapper-menu-item" class="rows-menu-wrapper-menu-item"><label class="form-label text-truncate rows-menu-wrapper-menu-item-label">Open Menu</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.rows-menu-wrapper-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: rgba(26,26,26,0.11);
}
```

Placing the menu using JS:-

```
    // top position
    var topY = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
    var topX = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left + document.documentElement.scrollLeft - 250            
    
    newPaper.find(".rows-menu-wrapper").css('top' , topY + 'px' )
    newPaper.find(".rows-menu-wrapper").css('left' , topX + 'px' )

    $('body').append(newPaper)
    

    var paperHeight = newPaper.css('height').replace('px' , '') - 400

    var delta = (e.clientY - newPaper.css('height').replace('px' , ''))
    delta = parseFloat(delta.toString().replace('-' , '') )
    delta = delta * 1.5

    if ( paperHeight <=  e.clientY   ){newPaper.find(".rows-menu-wrapper").css('top' , topY - delta + 'px' )}
```

I Checked many guides but never understand how it is work.

I would be greatful if someone make it simple for me :(

UPDATE1

```
I managet to get around of this with below:
            // top position
            var topY = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
            var topX = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left + document.documentElement.scrollLeft - 250  
            
            newPaper.find(".rows-menu-wrapper").css('left' , topX + 'px' )
            newPaper.find(".rows-menu-wrapper").css('top' , topY + 'px' )
            

            $('body').append(newPaper)

            var totalHeight = newPaper.css('height').replace('px' , '')
            var clickY = e.clientY 
            var elementHight = newPaper.find(".rows-menu-wrapper").css('height').replace('px' , '')
            
            var delta = totalHeight - clickY - elementHight

            if (delta <=  0){topY =   topY - elementHight + 20   }

            newPaper.find(".rows-menu-wrapper").css('top' ,  topY + 'px' )
```

IDK if this approach is ok or not clean.